# AngularJS || Ignore ngBlur on element blur when executing other function that does blur

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

While developing I have encountered an issue of firing blur two times, when i need to fire it only once.

Both ng-blur and ng-enter final actions are to make request to database, in our case 2 requests are done, when only 1 needed - or from ng-blur or from ng-enter. The problem is that ng-enter behaviour are causing to lose focus on element, which is connected to ng-blur.

Here are my two questions:

- Is there a way to prevent Angularjs to fire an ng-blur on todo div
  when ng-enter is executed ?
- If there is no solution for first question, I really hope that there
  is, then what options do I have ?

Below you can see parts of code that are responsible for my issue.

**template.html**

```
   <div ng-repeat="todo in todos" ng-enter="stopEditTodo($index, $event, todo);" ng-dblclick="editTodo($event);">
        <div class="card-details">
            <div class="card-content">
                <span ng-blur="stopEditTodo($index, $event, todo);">
                        {{todo.title}}
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**controller.js**

```
app.controller('homeController', function($scope, Todos, $state){

    $scope.editTodo = function($event) {
        var text = angular.element(angular.element(event.currentTarget).find('span')[0]);
        $event.preventDefault();
        text.attr("contenteditable", "true");
    }

    $scope.stopEditTodo = function($index, $event, todo) {
        angular.element(event.currentTarget).removeAttr('contenteditable');
    }
});
```

**directive.js**

```
app.directive('ngEnter', function () {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        element.bind("keydown keypress", function (event) {
            if(event.which === 13) {
                scope.$apply(function (){
                    scope.$eval(attrs.ngEnter);
                });

                event.preventDefault();
            }
        });
    };
});
```

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `ng-blur` triggers an `$evalAsync`, there's not really anything you can do in `ng-enter` to stop it from happening.

On the other hand, you have a few options:

#### Option #1 - check if the content was still editable when `stopEditTodo` fired

```
var target = angular.element(event.target);
if (target.attr('contenteditable')) {
    target.removeAttr('contenteditable');
    // fire request
}
```

Note that all of this is better done via a completely custom directive to encapsulate the direct DOM manipulation.

See [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/RG3FZBWgwVgPhblCiOSF?p=preview) for an example.

#### Option #2 - debounce

This is much more "hacky" but it usually does the trick - use a `debounce` function (i.e. [Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.2#debounce)) to make your handler fire only once per every X milliseconds. That is, something like this:

```
$scope.stopEditTodo = _.debounce(function($index, $event, todo) {
    angular.element(event.currentTarget).removeAttr('contenteditable');
    // fire request
}, 300);
```

This should do the trick for most usage scenarios.

**Side note**: it seems that you should be using `event.target` instead of `event.currentTarget`, as the latter will always refer to the parent `div` instead of the actual list item (which you want). Alternatively, you can move `ng-enter` to the list item instead of the parent.

Comment: After moving ng-enter to list item problem was solved! To ensure no more http requests are done simple check of "has title changed" does the trick.